# Is there a bicyclic irregular pentagon in integers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, polygons

Is there a bicyclic irregular pentagon in integers, i.e. is there a pentagon, the length of each side is integer and unique such that it has a circumcircle and an inner circle as well?

If it does exist, can we find the one with the smallest area?

OR can we show that it does (not) exist?

Comment: Ajai Choudry, Cyclic pentagons and hexagons with integer sides, diagonals and areas, https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00345 has some formulas that may be useful in pursuing this problem, although I see nothing in that paper about inscribed circles, only circumcircles.

Comment: There are also some formulas that might prove useful at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_polygon

Comment: What do you mean by unique? That all side lengths are distinct?

Comment: Observation: Let $P$ and $Q$ be two conics. Let $E$ be the set of pairs $(p,q) \in P \times Q$ such that the line $\overline{pq}$ is tangent to $Q$ at $q$. Then $E$ is an algebraic curve of genus $1$, and finding an $n$-gon $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$ inscribed in $P$ and circumscribed around $Q$ is equivalent to finding an $n$-torsion point on $E$. Since elliptic curves with rational $5$-torsion are plentiful, my guess is that the answer to this question is "yes", but I haven't figured out what the distance $d(p,q)$ is as a function on $E$.

Comment: This has a clean formulation in polar coordinates: Are there five angles $\alpha_i$ such that any four of  the points $PQRST$ with $r=\sec(\alpha_{i+1}-\alpha_i)$, $\theta=\alpha_{i+1}+\alpha_i$ satisfy Ptolemy’s theorem (eg $PQ\ RS + QR\ SP = PR\ QS$) while the five distances $PQ, QR, RS, ST, TP$ are distinct rationals?